# SQL Server upgrade from 2014 to 2017 and sequential numbers

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

One of my users ran the following code

```
set nocount on;

with R0 as
(
    select 1 as f1 
    union all 
    select 1 
    union all 
    select 1 
    union all 
    select 1 
    union all 
    select 1
),
R1 as (select a.f1 as f1 from R0 a cross join R0 b),
R2 as (select a.f1 as f1 from R1 a cross join R1 b),
R3 as (select a.f1 as f1 from R2 a cross join R2 b)
select top 350000 f1 
into t1 
from R3
go 

set nocount off 

declare @v1 int = 12345 

update a 
set @v1 = a.f1 = @v1+1
from t1 a
GO 

select * from t1 order by 1 

drop table t1
```

In SQL Server 2014 he got the numbers sequentially; like this:

```
12346
12347
12348
```

But in SQL Server 2017, he gets the following results:

```
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12346
12347
12347
12347
```

etc

I thought this was because of IDENTITY_CACHE but turned that off with same results.

Also tried installing CU12 on an instance but same effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi 

Just figured out it had nothing to do with the SQL upgrade but it does have something to do with the compatibility level 
If i set it to SQL 2012 or earlier it gives it to me sequentially but anything above that it has the same wrong affect 

Know how to solve it now but still dont know why 
Thanks 
Eben

Comment: Can't reproduce on SQL Server 2017 with compatibility for 2017.

Comment: Can you tell me what your MAXDOP / CTFP settings are?

Comment: `set @v1 = a.f1 = @v1+1` - That's called quirky update, and it's undocumented and known for having different behaviors under different conditions. Personally I've never used quirky updates before exactly because of what I've just written -  perhaps your client should think of a more stable way to get the desired result.